# I bought a new notebook with one partition and windows preinstalled. How do I create new partitions?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, partitioning, data-recovery

I have a 500GB hard disk. I want to split it up into a 200GB C and 300GB D rive. I want to put all my data on D partition so I can restore windows to C if some =thing goes wrong without losing any data on D. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 has a built in shrink partition feature in disk management. You can then format the non windows partitioned space as you wish.

[Tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: How do I do this? Is this option reversible??

Comment: It can be reversed by using the Extend partition option. Tutorial on how to use it added to the question.

Answer (score 3):

I would say [Partition Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PartitionMagic) is a good option for you. Even though Symantec no longer offers it, you might get it from somewhere else.

Comment: Will I be able to recover my entire C partition from my recovery partition to factory state without deleting data on the other partitions I create?

Comment: Yes, you will...

Answer (score 1):

[Parted Magic](http://www.partedmagic.com) is able to do partition resizing.  You can then use the built in Windows backup utility (assuming Vista or 7) to backup whatever data you wish.  Or, you can use a disk imaging tool like [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org) to create an image of the C partition, which is handy if you desire to restore to a blank slate or a predefined configuration.

Comment: I already have a recovery partition from my manufacturer(Sony).